# Rake preconfiguration?

Tags: ruby, rake

How do I do this in the Ruby-way?

```
# Rakefile

desc "Run task on server #1"
task :one do
    # Do somethin on server 1
    Srv1.exec "..."
end

desc "Run task on server #2"
task :two do
    # Do somethin on server 2
    Srv2.exec "..."
end

desc "Run task on both servers"
task :both do
    # Do somethin on both servers
    Serv1.exec "..."
    Serv2.exec "..."
end
```

How do I require the end execution configuration code? How do I do scaling (if I need Serv3)? Should `Serv1` be a class or something else?

What I need to do is to control a Vagrant VM with Rake, run custom tasks inside Vagrant, synchronize data with the host system, run some code on production and send the result to Vagrant, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, I'll fix a minor correction for your model. Do the `both` task with more simple method:

```
desc "Run task on both servers"
task :both => [ :one, :two ]
```

> How do I require the end execution configuration code? How do I do scaling (if I need Serv3)? Should Serv1 be a class or something else?

Just create a class `Serv`, and pass to it a number of server or something else. So you'll get:

```
desc "Run task on a server"
task :one do
   # Do somethin on a server
   Serv.new( ENV[ 'SERVER_NUMBER' ] ).exec "..."
end

desc "Run task on all servers"
task :one do
   # Do somethin on all servers
   Serv.exec "..."
end
```

Comment: Looks like that! But how to store and manage server's configurations? Should it be JSON, YAML or ruby hash object?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do some things on multiple servers, `rake` might not be quite the best tool for the job. Maybe you want to check out `Capistrano` which is usually used for deploying software, but also can be a tool to do general things remotely.

Comment: Capistrano is more deployment tool with it's own philosophy and Rake is task runner. I wish to make primitive solution to learn ruby well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I've solved the problem myself with loading two files in head of `Rakefile` the first is `server.rb` with server class, the second is `init.rb` with server instantiating code `Server1 = Server.new({:user=>'...` which is accessable from tasks in `Rackfile`.